# Nest js Prisma Serverless Prisma Cannot find module './prisma/client/index'

Tags: nestjs, serverless, prisma

Please forgive my dumbness, I am new to the concept and stackoverflow community. I have been following tutorial from freeCodeCamp's NestJs Course for Beginner.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHTA143_b-s&t=21s
And I have been try to use serverless framework to deploy. Whenever I request to endpoints, I I get the error of
Import Module Error: Prisma Cannot find module './prisma/client/index'.

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

My prisma code is : https://github.com/Jaethem8y/research-nestjs/tree/main/prisma

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class PrismaService extends PrismaClient {
  constructor(config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      datasources: {
        db: {
          url: config.get('DATABASE_URL'),
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

Prisma Service code is: https://github.com/Jaethem8y/research-nestjs/tree/main/src/prisma

and serverless.yml : https://github.com/Jaethem8y/research-nestjs/blob/main/serverless.yml

```
service: research-serverless

frameworkVersion: '3'

plugins:
  - serverless-jetpack

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x
  region: us-east-2 

functions:
  api:
    handler: dist/lambda.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: any
          path: /{proxy+}
```

I run npm build then sls deploy. I have no idea what is current issue, and failed to find answer in google due to lack of my skills. Please help me find the solution. Thank you for your time.

I have been tried to google the similar issues, but I could not find one. Seems like the typeorm version of the app is running fine. I am wondering what could cause this issue.

Comment: The links that you have posted are inaccessible. Can you please make them accessible or update them? 

You can try to follow this guide here: https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/deploying-to-aws-lambda

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you should verify whether or not your repository is actually public before posting links to them. I think your repo is set to private.

Secondly, the error you described comes from the fact that the prisma client does not exist. Please make sure you use `prisma generate` command to actually generate the client after declaring your models in prisma.schema. You should also verify whether or not you are generating the client in your container image (if this applies).

Comment: I got bit by this running locally after I nuked `node_modules` to reinstall everything and forgot that the Prisma client code gets generated in there.

Answer (score -1):

I met the same issue a few days ago,
but in my case, I make use Vercel as the deployment platform

The  serverless platform can't recognize absolute import;
instead, I have to opt for relative import, and after modify the import method,
it works.